# SSIS > Variable > Value = one of the list source property

Tags: ssis

I have a variable "vSourceName" and I would like the set the value for this variable to be "Data Flow's source" property.

How would I do this? I did some google for not sure what keyword to use. I am sorry if it seems like I did not do my homework. new to SSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using an OLE DB Source, just change the Data Access Mode dropdown on the source to :  Table Name or View Name from Variable.  Then choose your variable from the Variable Name dropdown.

Comment: Actually, I am using OLE DB source but I need some property info into a variable from "SharePoint List Source". There is a property called "ShareListName" and I want this value to be in the variable. Possible ?

Comment: I've never messed with a SharePoint List Source before... but this is the only thought I have.  If the SharePoint List Source is within a DataFlowTask, then from your main workflow, click on the data flow task, in the properties window scroll down to 'Expressions' and click the ellipses.  In the window that pops up, click the drop-down arrow and look for the name of your SharePoint List Source node, and hopefully a property off of that.  If you see it, click it, and then assign a variable to that.  Then use the same variable for your OLE DB Source.  Hopefully I understood your refined question

Comment: The property you would be looking for is obviously 'ShareListName' sorry I couldn't fit that in the above comment.

Comment: could you please provide a screen shot? I dont see the Expression for either sources (ole or sharepoint). I do see Expression builder for the variable but neither sources are listed in the expression builder box.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I see them now. It was all the way down. Thanks so much.

Comment: No problem man, glad to help.  Finding the way to inject variables into some of the other component properties was a big "Ah hah!" moment for me.